# Probability that two-digit randomly-picked number is prime?

Tags: probability

I have a math problem that I am not able to solve.

It goes like this:
Determine the probability that randomly picked two-digit number is prime.

There are 90 two-digit numbers 10-99.

*I know I can count them and say its num_of_primes / 90, but I am interested in the general approach to this kind of problems.

Comment: I'm not too good at prime theory, but you should find prime counting function and its approximates to be very useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function.

Comment: Well, in general you could invoke the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) to see that the probability that a randomly chosen integer $≤x$ is prime is about $\frac 1{\ln(x)}$.  It's only an estimate though (asymptotically exact for large $x$). For $x=100$ this yields about $.217$ whereas the true value is $.25$.  (Note:  I'm only looking at numbers of "at most two digits".  You can modify the calculation to get "exactly two digits" if you like).

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [approximation of the number of primes between 1 and X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), divide that by X.

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is the [prime-counting function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(x)$. It is a hard function to compute, but it is about $x\ln(x)$ if x is large. Just work out the approximation at both ends of the interval you want, and subtract to get a rough idea of the number of primes in that interval; the probability is then one step more.